# How do I create an RDD from input directory containing text files?

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, bigdata, analysis, apache-spark-mllib

I am working with the 20 newsgroup dataset. Basically, I have a folder and n text files. The Files in the folder belong to the topic the folder is named. I have 20 such folders. How do I load all this data into Spark and make an RDD out of it, so that I can apply machine learning transformations and actions on them? (Eg: like naive bayes). I'm looking for ways to create a RDD. Not help with how to apply the algorithms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use SparkConext.wholeTextFiles(...). It reads a directory and creates RDD for all the files within that directory.